# Graph Python challenge 2 (revised)

Tags: python, performance, graph

I'm looking for ways to optimize a function that I wrote as an answer to this problem in Python:

> You and your rescued prisoners need to get out of this collapsing
>   death trap - and fast! Unfortunately, some of the prisoners have been
>   weakened by their long imprisonment and can't run very fast. Their
>   friends are trying to help them, but this escape would go a lot faster
>   if you also pitched in. The exit doors have begun to close, and if you
>   don't make it through in time, you'll be trapped! You need to grab as
>   many prisoners as you can and get through the exit doors before they
>   close.
>
> The time it takes to move from your starting point to all of the
>   prisoners and to the exit door will be given to you in a square matrix
>   of integers. Each row will tell you the time it takes to get to the
>   start, first prisoner, second prisoner, ..., last prisoner, and the
>   exit door in that order. The order of the rows follows the same
>   pattern (start, each prisoner, exit door). The prisoners can jump into
>   your arms, so picking them up is instantaneous, and arriving at the
>   exit door at the same time as it seals still allows for a successful,
>   if dramatic, escape. (Don't worry, any prisoner you don't pick up will
>   be able to escape with you since they no longer have to carry the ones
>   you did pick up.) You can revisit different spots if you wish, and
>   moving to the exit door doesn't mean you have to immediately leave -
>   you can move to and from the exit door to pick up additional prisoners
>   if time permits.
>
> In addition to spending time traveling between prisoners, some paths
>   interact with security checkpoints and add time back to the clock.
>   Adding time to the clock will delay the closing of the exit doors, and
>   if the time goes back up to 0 or a positive number after the doors
>   have already closed, it triggers the doors to reopen. Therefore, it
>   might be possible to walk in a circle and keep gaining time: that is,
>   each time a path is traversed, the same amount of time is used or
>   added.
>
> Write a function of the form answer(times, time_limit) to calculate
>   the most prisoners you can pick up and which prisoners they are, while
>   still escaping through the exit doors before they close for good. If
>   there are multiple sets of prisoners of the same number, return the
>   set of prisoners with the lowest prisoner IDs (as indexes) in sorted
>   order. The prisoners are represented as a sorted list by prisoner ID,
>   with the first prisoner being 0. There are at most 5 prisoners, and
>   time_limit is a non-negative integer that is at most 999.

The function that I wrote is:

```
def answer(times,time_limit):
    n=len(times)
    mindic=min(min(times))
    dist = map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , times)
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n): 
                dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j] ,dist[i][k]+ dist[k][j])
    def find_path(times, start, end,time,temp, path=[]):
        if start != 0 and start != end :
            path = path + [start-1]
        if start == end and len(temp) < len(path):
            temp=path
        if start == end and (time-min(times[start][0:-1]) < mindic or len(path)== n-2):
            return path
        best=None
        for i in range(n):
            if time-times[start][i] >= mindic and start != i  and i != 0 and i-1 not in path:
                newpath = find_path(times, i, end,time-times[start][i],temp, path)
                if newpath != None :   
                    if not best or len(newpath) > len(best):
                        best=newpath
        if best == None:
            best=temp
        return best
    res =find_path(dist, 0, n-1,time_limit,[])
    return res
```

Calling the function will be something like this:

```
answer([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]],3)
```

and the answer for the above example is:

```
[0, 1]
```

It will only be able to save the prisoners with index 0 and index 1.

For example, in the case of:

```
[ 
   [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start
   [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = prisoner 0 
   [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = prisoner 1
   [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = prisoner 2
   [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = exit door    
 ]
```

and a time limit of 1, the five inner array rows designate the starting point, prisoner 0, prisoner 1, prisoner 2, and the exit door respectively. You could take the path:

> ```
> Start End Delta Time Status
>
>     -   0     -    1 exit door initially open
>     0   4    -1    2
>     4   2     2    0
>     2   4    -1    1
>     4   3     2   -1 exit door closes
>     3   4    -1    0 exit door reopens; you and the saved persons exit
> ```

With this solution, you would pick up prisoner 1 and 2. This is the best combination for this case, so the answer is [1, 2].

Generally, it should be something like this:

> ```
> Inputs:
>     (int) times = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
>     (int) time_limit = 3
> Output:
>     (int list) [0, 1]
>
> Inputs:
>     (int) times = [[0, 2, 2, 2, -1], [9, 0, 2, 2, -1], [9, 3, 0, 2, -1], [9, 3, 2, 0, -1], [9, 3, 2, 2, 0]]
>     (int) time_limit = 1
> Output:
>     (int list) [1, 2]
> ```